# FullCalendar Javascript 5.11.0 and loading data on calendar

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I was using FullCalendar javascript on my wordpress's plugin... an old library so I updated  to latest 5.11.0 so I had to rewrite a bit the function to manage calendar as follow:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('mycalendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {      
    locale: locale.substring(0, 2),
    lazyFetching: false,
    loading: function(isLoading) { if (isLoading) { box = new ajaxLoader(".mycalendar"); } },
    customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
          text: 'custom!',
          click: function() {
            alert('clicked the custom button!');
          }
        }
    },
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'today prevYear,prev,next,nextYear',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'myCustomButton'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2020-09-12',
    dateClick: function() {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
    },          
    events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        let url = 'http://'+window.location.host+'/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/retrievedata/retrievedata.db.php?action=load_monthlyevents&' + new URLSearchParams({
            start: info.startStr,
            end: info.endStr
        });         
        fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
            //const isEmpty = Object.keys(response).length === 0;
            //if (!isEmpty)
            return response.json();
        })          
        .then(function(jsonResponse) {
            // do something with jsonResponse
            //alert(jsonResponse);
    
            //console.log(jsonResponse);
            var events = [];

            jsonResponse.forEach(function(el) {
                //alert(el.id + " - " + el.start + " - " + el.end + " - " + el.data1 + " - " + el.data2 + " - " + el.color);
                var event = {
                  id: el.id,
                  start: el.start,
                  end: el.end,
                  title: el.data1 + ' (' + el.data2 + ')',
                  backgroundColor: el.color,
                  textColor: '#000000'
                };
                events.push(event);
            });
                                    
            console.log(events);
            box.remove();
            successCallback(events);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            box.remove();
            failureCallback(err);
        });         
    },
    eventDidMount: function(info) {
        element.qtip({ 
            content: { text: $.ajax({url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/retrievedata/retrievedata.db.php?action=load_eventdetails&ID="+info.event.id, async:false}).responseText }, 
            position: { effect: false, viewport: $('#mydata_grid'), adjust: { method: 'flipinvert' } } 
        });
    },
    eventMouseEnter: function(event, jsEvent) { $(jsEvent.target).css('cursor','pointer'); },
    eventClick: function(info) {
        /* load event in panel */
        alert("data id: " + info.event.id);
    }           
});

calendar.render();
```

The matter is I get correctly data from database as JSON but it doesn't show those events on calendar... maybe I missed something or I formatted in wrong way the structure to pass to the FullCalendar?

I tried also with giving directly to FullCalendar the JSON object to let him manage it with this code:

```
events: {
    url: "http://"+window.location.host+"/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/retrievedata/retrievedata.db.php",
    //method: 'GET',
    extraParams: {action:'load_monthlyevents'},
    //format: 'json',
    //cache: false,
    //async: false,
    failure: function () { box.remove(); },
    success: function (data) {
        box.remove();
        
        //callback(data);
        successCallback(data);                  
        //return data;
    }           
},
```

but in this way it says successCallback/callback is not defined...
And this is the JSON sample I obtain from db with `console.log(jsonResponse)` :

```
[
    {id: '576', start: '2015-09-07 12:00:00', end: '2015-09-07 17:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#A9F5F2'},
    {id: '581', start: '2015-10-02 07:00:00', end: '2015-10-02 17:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#A9F5F2'},
    {id: '582', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#A9F5F2'},
    {id: '583', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#A9F5A9'},
    {id: '584', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#F3F781'},
    {id: '585', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#F5BCA9'},
    {id: '586', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#A9BCF5'},
    {id: '587', start: '2015-10-08 06:00:00', end: '2015-10-08 11:00:00', data1: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', data2: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', color: '#F5A9F2'}
]
```

Any direction would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: can you post the json data you are using to load events in question ?

Comment: Hello @ShoyebSheikh , thank you for your answer.... I just re-edited the post with the JSON result I obtain from db via `console.log(jsonResponse)` .....

Comment: If that's what is being returned then you should just be able to write `events: { url: "http://"+window.location.host+"/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/retrievedata/retrievedata.db.php", extraParams: {action:'load_monthlyevents'} },` and nothing else - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxpaWLj . Of course if you want the title to be made from some of the other fields you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform to adjust the incoming event objects before they are rendered

Answer (score 0):

First get the json string in a variable beforehand,

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($json_array); ?>;
```

after you have the json in variable load the events like below,

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     ....
     ....
     ....
    events: json,
     ....
     ....
     ....       
});
```

Comment: 1) That's not valid JSON, 2) fullCalendar's `events` parameter accepts an array literal, not a JSON string. (You must supply JSON from a URL if you define events as a URL, but if you define it as a literal it must be an array, not a string - fullCalendar will think the string is an attempt to supply a URL not a direct list of events). 3) an events feed is a far more efficient solution anyway, if the application can support it (because it supports filtering the events by date and/or other params, so that only the needed events can be provided, not just a dump of the whole database).

Comment: @ADyson result of a `json_encode` is a string and it works in full calendar.

Comment: Only because JS will interpret it as an array literal, if you don't put it within JS quote marks. But as I said, the code here is not valid JSON (it's only valid as an array literal, for which the syntax requirements are much less strict). If you just remove the quote marks here it'd be fine - it would be interpreted directly as a literal...no need for strings, no need for JSON.parse (which won't work anyway). Also you've single-quoted a string containing single quotes...so it's not even a valid _string_, never mind anything else. Do you test your answers before you post them? I guess not.

Comment: But anyway regardless of all that it's still really inefficient compared to creating a feed, which the OP has done with no problem already. There's really no need to resort to this basic mode of supplying events. They only seem to have a small problem with the newer fullcalendar event feed syntax, as I've shown in my other comments.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson & @ShoyebSheikh , I changed the events: passing directly the php `json_encode` 's result to the FullCalendar and it seems working but not as I expected... I wanted the color item passed as backgroundColor of current single event so I changed the item as ` 'backgroundColor':'#F3F781' ` but I see only like a ball color, not the entire event background... and also I see a '6' next to the color ball which shouldn't be there... why?

Comment: @Luigino Why resort to json_encode when you can fix your event feed - I already showed you above that it would work ok with a simple syntax change. There's even a demo! But the 6 is there because it's the time of the event. The ball is there because it's controlled by a setting in fullCalendar - read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay

Comment: @Luigino I used `color` property  in json data it worked in my case,  if my answer helped you can accept and mark it as a solution thanks

Comment: I tried to put in FullCalendar default `eventColor: 'white'` then passing from json_encode structure `'color':'#AF5493'` but it still show only a dot instead of background, so I tried to add also in json_encode `'display':'background'` as docs says but in this last way the event doesn't show at all...

Comment: @Luigino `'display': 'background'` makes it into a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events). Read the documentation more carefully. I think `display: "block"` is what you're actually looking for there.

Comment: @ADyson , you were right....tought "background" meant the current event background... now it looks working... only I have now to add the old spinner while loading and switching it off when events page are loaded...

Comment: OK, now it looks as like as it was with the old 2.3.4 library.... I want to mark solution to both you ADyson & ShoyebSheikh because both of you helped me anyway... is there a way to give both you the worth?... :-)

Comment: @Luigino not really no because I only made comments not answers. And this answer, as it stands, is still a bit incorrect (it needs editing) and also as I've said before I don't think it's the right approach...you should be fixing your data feed rather than restorting to injecting data directly into the JS as effectively hard-coded info.

Comment: @ADyson yes in fact I modified just as like as : `events: { url: "blahblahblah", extraParams: {action:'load_monthlyevents'} }` and nothing else so the json_encode from php would feed directly to FullCalendar and in fact it worked....

Comment: @Luigino glad it worked for you, sometimes things work when you think out of the box.